# How to get a value from onChange in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get value from onChange using `setState` but for some reason when I write text on `input` I get an error like `Axis.map is not a function`

Also,I'd like to delete `Axis`data singly from the last one using `splice` or `pop` but whenever I click the delete button the `Axis` data disappeared except the first one.

#### Set Elements

```
    const SetElements = ({
    ...
    }) => {
      const [Axis, setAxis] = useState([]);

      const AxisHandler = e => {
        setAxis([
          ...Axis,
          {
            label: "",
            data: "",
            backgroundColor: "",
          },
        ]);
      };

      const deleteAxis = () => {
        setAxis(Axis.splice(-1, 1));
      };

      return (
              <>
                <button onClick={AxisHandler}>add Line</button>

                {Axis.length !== 1 && (
                  <button onClick={deleteAxis}>delete Line</button>
                )}
                
                 {Axis.map((element, index) => (
                <>
                  <AppendingAxis
                  
                    Axis={Axis}
                    setAxis={setAxis}
                    element={element}
                    index={index}
                  />
                </>
              ))}
              </>
            )
```

#### AppendingAxis

```
    const AppendingAxis = ({
      index,
      setAxis,
      Axis,
    }) => {
      console.log(Axis);
      return (
        <AxisSetting>
          <h4>{index + 2}Y Axis setting</h4>
          <span>
            <input
              placeholder={index + 2 + "setting"}
              type="textarea"
              onChange={e => setAxis((Axis[index].label = e.target.value))}
            />
          </span>
```

Comment: can you please share your code on code sandbox??

Comment: check the return of splice, in ur code ,splice return an array of the last item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is state mutation in the `AppendingAxis` component.

```
onChange={e => setAxis((Axis[index].label = e.target.value))}
```

You should shallow copy state, and nested state, then update specific properties.

```
onChange={e => setAxis(Axis => Axis.map((el, i) => i === index
  ? {
      ...el,
      label: e.target.value
    }
  : el,
)}
```

I'm not a fan of passing the state updater function on to children as this make it the child component's responsibility to maintain your state invariant. I suggest moving this logic into the parent component so it can maintain control over how state is updated.

SetElements parent

```
const changeHandler = index => e => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  setAxis(Axis => Axis.map((el, i) => i === index
    ? {
        ...el,
      label: value
      }
    : el,
  );
};

...

<AppendingAxis
  Axis={Axis}
  onChange={changeHandler(index)}
/>
```

AppendingAxis child

```
const AppendingAxis = ({ Axis, onChange }) => {
  console.log(Axis);
  return (
    <AxisSetting>
      <h4>{index + 2}Y Axis setting</h4>
      <span>
        <input
          placeholder={index + 2 + "setting"}
          type="textarea"
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </span>
```

And for completeness' sake, your delete handler looks to also have a mutation issue.

```
const deleteAxis = () => {
  setAxis(Axis.splice(-1, 1));
};
```

`.splice` mutates the array in-place and returns an array containing the deleted elements. This is quite the opposite of what you want I think. Generally you can use `.filter` or `.slice` to generate new arrays and not mutate the existing one.

```
const deleteAxis = () => {
  setAxis(Axis => Axis.slice(0, -1)); // start at 0, end at second to last
};
```

Comment: Really like the way you shallow copy and update state with one `map` function. Earlier I would do a shallow copy, then update seperately. Started using this way, so thanks Drew! :D

Comment: @SinanYaman Yeah, definitely the correct tool for the job. Welcome. :)

Comment: @DrewReese Always you answer the best! Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of this line:

```
onChange={e => setAxis((Axis[index].label = e.target.value))}
```

Create a function:

```
const handleAxisChange = (e, index) => {
    Axis[index].label = e.target.value;
    setAxis(new Array(...Axis));
}
```

And then change set the `onChange` like this:

```
onChange={e => handleAxisChange(e, index)}
```

Comment: You are still mutating state with `Axis[index].label = e.target.value` You should shallow copy it first. Right idea but just a bit incorrect execution

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because of you don't mutate state correctly. You should make a shallow copy of the state. You can change `AppendingAxis` to this code:

```
 const AppendingAxis = ({
      index,
      setAxis,
      Axis,
    }) => {
      console.log(Axis);
      const onChange = (e,index)=>{
       let copy = [...Axis];
       copy[index].label = e.target.value; 
       setAxis(copy);
      }
      return (
        <AxisSetting>
          <h4>{index + 2}Y Axis setting</h4>
          <span>
            <input
              placeholder={index + 2 + "setting"}
              type="textarea"
              onChange={e => onChange(e,index))}
            />
          </span>
```

Comment: Instead of `let a = copy.filter((x) => x.index == index)[0]; let itemIndex = copy.indexOf(a);` you can use `let itemIndex = copy.findIndex(x => x.index === index)`

Comment: @SinanYaman Thank you for your attention. But we need the index of `a` to update the `state` :  `copy[itemIndex] = a;`. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't rename the variable my bad. You can just get the index without needing `a` at all was my point. Same result, less code :)

Comment: Why would you iterate the state 3 times just to copy it and update a specific index? `index` isn't a property on the elements being iterated over.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your attention. Please check my code again and say your opinion.

Comment: Well, you still iterate it a second time with `Array.prototype.findIindex`, but you already have that since it is passed to the function. You could just use the passed `index` and `copy[index] = { ...copy[index], label: value }` (*you need to also shallow copy the element*) to keep it to a single loop.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you a lot. I've learnt to less code,  more power! :)